# Switching between activities Android

Tags: android, layout

I have an Android app with two classes:
-MainActivity
-SecondActivity
I have also two layouts for these classes (they are pretty similar).
I want to switch between these activities by 'shifting' to the right or to the left.
All materials I find are about switching by button.

Comment: Do you mean android Material Tab layout: https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage

Comment: Thank you :) I think that's it.

Comment: This sounds like a `ViewPager`, although you would need to use `Fragments` rather than `Activity`s

Answer (score 2):

Anyone would recommend using `Fragments` and `ViewPager` instead of `Activity` since you want sliding action and make use of the Android [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html).

[Here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/) is a **tutorial** that you can draw a basic idea from.